# registration with email verification with dj-rest-auth

Tags: django-rest-framework

Hi everyone I am developing a website with django rest framework for backend and I am using `dj-rest-auth` for authentication. And I want to implement registration with email veification, based on documents of `dj-rest-auth` these are urls for registration:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),

path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),

path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),  
path('dj-rest-auth/registration/verify-email/',
  include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),  
]
```

and in settings I did these things:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'corsheaders',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dj_rest_auth',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
]

SITE_ID = 1
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True

LOGIN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/accounts_api/api/v1/dj-rest-auth/login'
```

and I am using `gmail smtp` for `smtp`.

But after sending a user info for registration I got this error:

```
Reverse for 'account_confirm_email' not found. 'account_confirm_email' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Can anyone tell me about where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This was explained in the FAQ section, [read the first question](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#faq).

Comment: thanks dear mahmud but why they didnt mention anything in API endpoints section?!!!

Comment: I think because it's related to using it with SPA only or something, so it was on FAQ not in core docs, you can open an issue or submit a PR to the repo to address this confusion.

Comment: If this answer answers your question, please, mark it as accepted then.

Comment: How did you manage to solve this, Cause I have the same issue

Comment: @alpha027 did you check closed issues on the repo? I believe you will find some useful answers there

Comment: finally I managed to solve it, through github issues and other stack overflow questions